# dsl script for maven type Jenkins jobs

Tags: jenkins, dsl

I writing the DSL Script for maven type Jenkins jobs.

https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/mavenJob-properties

With help of above link I written almost DSL script, but unable to find the DSL script for "Build and Build setting" step sections(For maven type jobs).

Please help me how to mention the above two steps in DSL script.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for build step for maven type jobs

add the build step (goal) after pre-build step like

```
   mavenJob('example-1') {

      preBuildSteps {

      }

      goals('clean install -DskipTests')

      postBuildSteps {

      }

   }
```